# Javascript code for simple slide show page is not working

Tags: javascript

Here is an example from the book "DOM Scripting: Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model." I don't know why it's not working. When I click on the list, the pictures should be changed in the placeholder. But now they only open in the window.

Thank you!

```js
window.onload = prepareGallery;

function prepareGallery() {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
  var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
  var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      return showPic(this) ? false : true;
    }
  }
}

function showPic(whichpic) {
  if (!document.getElementById("placeholder")) return false;
  var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
  if (placeholder.nodeNae != "IMG") return false;
  placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
  if (document.getElementById("description")) {
    var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title") ? whichpic.getAttribute("title") : "";
    if (description.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
      description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Snapshots</h1>
  <ul id="imagegallery">
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_bhfwqijyyfzgpexgwvpkkqc7v.jpg" title="Flower in Spring">Flower</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_yh5i09po53igg59opdscqeauf.jpg" title="Building">Building</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_8_vmhpdnbefvxhlof0lgdwot6.jpg" title="Snow in a cold day">Cold Day</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_ugfgxkpb_8un6pz2ljeuzmmws.jpg" title="Beautiful Sunset">Sunset</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p id="description">Choose an Image.</p>
  <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="my image gallery" id="placeholder" style="border: 2px solid #eaeaea">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: click `Run code snippet` button, then you will find one error, please fix it.

Comment: Not exactly related to the problem, but there's no need to check the existense of the native methods the have been available for more than a decade ... or maybe you should find a bit more fresh tutorial ..?

Comment: Thanks Teemu. I agree. It might be too old. Do you know any better tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

So I looked up the ebook. didn't want to buy it to answer a question, but I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Apress/dom-scripting-10) and couldn't find what chapter you'd be on to be using *just* this code. from what it looks like it, I can only guess you're on chapter 6, so take a look at the [example JS script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Apress/dom-scripting-10/master/chapter06/image_gallery/01/scripts/showPic.js) for that chapter, it works fine.  also, you have a syntax error on line 38 of your code "documnet" should probably be *document*. Would have made this a comment but couldn't.

Comment: Thank you! That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `if (placeholder.nodeNae != "IMG") return false;` `nodeNae` should be `nodeName`. Not sure why the snippet wasn't throwing an error.

```js
window.onload = prepareGallery;

function prepareGallery() {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
  var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
  var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      return showPic(this) ? false : true;
    }
  }
}

function showPic(whichpic) {
  if (!document.getElementById("placeholder")) return false;
  var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
  if (placeholder.nodeName != "IMG") return false;
  placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
  if (document.getElementById("description")) {
    var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title") ? whichpic.getAttribute("title") : "";
    if (description.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
      description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Snapshots</h1>
  <ul id="imagegallery">
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_bhfwqijyyfzgpexgwvpkkqc7v.jpg" title="Flower in Spring">Flower</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_yh5i09po53igg59opdscqeauf.jpg" title="Building">Building</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_8_vmhpdnbefvxhlof0lgdwot6.jpg" title="Snow in a cold day">Cold Day</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_ugfgxkpb_8un6pz2ljeuzmmws.jpg" title="Beautiful Sunset">Sunset</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p id="description">Choose an Image.</p>
  <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="my image gallery" id="placeholder" style="border: 2px solid #eaeaea">


</body>
</html>
```

This code seems pretty outdated so I'm going to write a newer one.

`const` is a block scoped variable that cannot have the value altered and cannot be redeclared. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

`.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll` return either a DOM object or a NodeList of matching nodes respectively. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Since `gallery_images` is a NodeList that means we can iterate over it with `.forEach`. In the `forEach` I am using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as shorthand for assigning the event listener to the `a` element.

`.forEach(image => image.addEventListener('click', showImage))` is the same as `.forEach(function() { this.addEventListener('click', showImage); }`.

If anything is confusing I can try and clarify it some more. I've linked to the docs for additional information.

```js
const gallery = document.querySelector('#imagegallery');
const gallery_images = document.querySelectorAll('#imagegallery a');
const placeholder = document.querySelector('#placeholder');

gallery_images.forEach(image => image.addEventListener('click', showImage));

function showImage(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the link from opening
  const source = this.href;
  const title = this.title;
  placeholder.src = source;
  placeholder.alt = title;
}
```

```html
<h1>Snapshots</h1>
<ul id="imagegallery">
  <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_bhfwqijyyfzgpexgwvpkkqc7v.jpg" title="Flower in Spring">Flower</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_yh5i09po53igg59opdscqeauf.jpg" title="Building">Building</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_8_vmhpdnbefvxhlof0lgdwot6.jpg" title="Snow in a cold day">Cold Day</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/large_288252_ugfgxkpb_8un6pz2ljeuzmmws.jpg" title="Beautiful Sunset">Sunset</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="description">Choose an Image.</p>
<img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="my image gallery" id="placeholder" style="border: 2px solid #eaeaea">
```